# Updating web services on ArcGIS Online using ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, web-service, update

I am attempting to tailor the code found on ESRI's website (https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/api-python/analytics/updating-your-hosted-feature-services-with-arcgis-pro-and-the-arcgis-api-for-python/) to update feature services on our Organization AGOL account. I can't get past this current error message:

[image]

Would anyone be willing to look at this code and see if they can find out where I've gone wrong?

[image]

Comment: Its better if you actually add the code and copy/paste the error message as text. These items are searchable where images are not. Further, the error is when trying to create the .SD file from the `CreateWebLayerSDDraft` command.  I'd try the few lines of code that makes the .SD file inside the Python window of ArcGIS Pro, it might help you troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

I think I see the error in your image. (this is why copy/pasting code is better than the image). From your error screen shot, its failing on the **CreateWebLayerSDDraft**  call.

After `FEATURE_ACCESS`, make sure that you have a double quote "" (its hard to tell if its a single quote. Single quote is bad).

The very last `True`, you have a " (quote) after it. Remove that.

```
arcpy.mp.CreateWebLayerSDDraft(mp, sddraft, sd_fs_name, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES', 'FEATURE_ACCESS','', True, True)
```

Comment: That seemed to get me somewhere! I added an additional quote after Feature_Access and removed the one after true. I am now getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 33, in <module>
  File "c:\program files\arcgis\pro\Resources\arcpy\arcpy\utils.py", line 163, in fn_
    arg_name].keys())))
ValueError: Invalid value for service_type: 'FEATURE_ACCESS,' (choices are: ['FEATURE_ACCESS', 'TILED'])

Comment: Any ideas on this one? I can try and add a picture of it if you can't tell from that text.

Comment: If you've copied directly off the blog post - the font used in the code is funky. Try deleting the `FEATURE_ACCESS` and retyping it with new quotes on it.

Comment: should it look like "FEATURE_ACCESS""     ?

Comment: I am getting a EOL while scanning string literal. Here is the code: # Create a new SDDraft and stage to SD
print('Creating SD file')
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
prj = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(prjPath)
mp = prj.listMaps()[0]
arcpy.mp.CreateWebLayerSDDraft(mp, sddraft, sd_fs_name, 'MY_HOSTED_SERVICES', 'FEATURE_ACCESS',", True, True)
arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)